# Как убрать лаги в ScrollView, который пролистывается под прозрачным navBar?

Tags: ios, swift

Попадаю в данный контроллер из navigationController, в котором есть tab bar. При переходе скрываю tabBar, а navigation bar делаю прозрачным, чтобы фото находилось прямо под кнопкой "назад" на главную. Для этого во viewWillAppear делаю следующее:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:  UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Проблемы:
1: При загрузке изначально все отображается вот так:
[image: Картинка1]

И уже потом через заметную для человеческого глаза задержку становится вот так (по сути как я и хочу): 
 [image: Картинка2]

2: Если свайпать вниз, то картинка и весь вью уплывает из под navigation bar, причем с какими-то странными подергиваниями и лагами (и также под этот navigation bar возвращается). Хотелось бы узнать как убрать эти лаги и заблокировать прокрутку вниз до такой меры, чтобы картинка не уплывала из под navbar и не оставляла пустое белое пространство. Есть подозрения что я не совсем правильно выставил constraints чтобы вообще реализовать работу этого scrollView, также напрягает то, что мне пришлось делать -44 для scroll view, чтобы он заполз под navigation bar, выглядит как-то костыльно.

[image: AutoLayout]

Comment: А в консоль какие-нибудь сообщения сыпятся? Например о констрейнах?

Comment: Подсказали привязать scrollView.top не к Safe Area - 44, а напрямую к SuperView. Плюс добавил отступ 20 чтобы все таки не залазить на status bar. Лаги ушли. Теперь загружается как надо, однако через долю секунды уплывает на 44 пикселя под Nav bar.